# конкатенация строки и двух условий if

Tags: php

Есть 'строка' в конце которой стоит Тег `<br>` нужно сделать перенос строки при двух переменных, отображение которых зависит от условия if

пример такой, в нем не происходит перенос корректно, тк написание выводит по итогу 3 строчки, а мне нужно одну:

```
if($x1 or $x2 != NULL){
echo 'текст: '; if ($x1 != NULL){echo $x1;} if ($x2 != NULL){echo $x2 . '<br>';}
}
```

мне нужно что бы строка выглядела так

```
if($x1 or $x2 != NULL){
echo 'текст: ' . $x1 . $x2 . '<br>';}
```

Дело в том что $x1 и $x2 попеременно могут пропадать из строки, а задача переносить курсор с новой строчки сразу же после всей строчи, но у меня не выходит сделать все в одну строку

**те это должно выглядеть так в текстовом виде**

```
какой то текст
нужный текст с перменной один или переменной два
какой то текст

или

какой то текст
нужный текст с перменной один
какой то текст

или

какой то текст
нужный текст с перменной два
какой то текст
```

Пол дня 'бьюсь' с этой задачей голова кипит, если кому-то покажется банальной, прошу строго не судить, учусь.

Comment: Мне одному не понятна суть? Может как-то иначе опишете?

Comment: Не, нифига не ясно.

Comment: вы лучше объясните на примере входных значений переменных, что хотите получить.

Comment: Если x1 или x2 есть, то

Выводим строку 

Если есть x1, то выводим строку+x1
Если есть x2, то выводим строку+x2
Если есть x1 и x2, то выводим строку+x1+x2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так Вы хотите сделать?

```
if($x1 or $x2 != NULL){
echo 'текст: '; if ($x1 != NULL){echo $x1;} if ($x2 != NULL){echo $x2;} echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает! Пол дня убил, перебирал все что смог, ваш вариант переносит так как нужно!

Comment: Пол дня это еще не много )

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите называется "Тернарный оператор"

```
if($x1 or $x2 != NULL){
  echo 'текст: ' . ($x1 != NULL?$x1:'') .($x2 != NULL?$x2:'') . '<br>';
}
```

Еще пример, если скобки ввели вас в заблуждение:

```
echo 'текст: ' . $x1!=NULL?$x1: . $x2!=NULL?$x2: . '<br>';
```

Comment: @Kirill Спасибо =) я и не заметил ее при копипасте =)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, он работает, но задача стоит чуть чуть по другому, есть условие для $x1 и $x2. Если $x1 или $x2 существуют, то выводим всю строку и в ней уже выводим или $x1 и $x2 или $x1 или $x2. Я пытаюсь в строку подставить еще условия вывода

Comment: так там именно это и есть =) вы на строку посмотрите внимательно =) и прочтите про тернарный оператор =) Это одна строка `'текст: ' . ($x1 != NULL?$x1:'') .($x2 != NULL?$x2:'') . '<br>'` и в ней 2 условия `(Условие?истина:ложь)` дополнил ответ вторым примером если вам так проще воспринимать.

Comment: Владимир, благодарю за помощь, но ваш ответ у меня выводит ошибку mvc при $x1 or $x2 == NULL, а при использовании if ошибка не отображается. Я видимо не так изъяснялся о сути задачи, нужно было переносить строку при условиях, а я зациклился на приведении к одной строки нескольких и конкатенации. Ваш ответ натолкнул меня на просмотр примеров с тернарным оператором.